# SVG animation class inside a class not working

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to understand SVG animation but there is some problem with the classes.

HTML document looks like that scheme:

```html
<svg>
<g class="group">
<circle class="one" ... >
<path class="two" ... > etc.
</g>
</svg
```

I want to animate these two elements, but when I refere to the group or svg it doesn't work. In the Codepen editor the code for the class is yellow (is active) but when I will place .one inside of a .group class, the .one class become passive (white).

```css
.one,
.two {
  transition: 0.3s all;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
 

.group:hover {
    .one {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    .two {
      transform: scale(2);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

In such a way it doesn't work. Classes .one and .two become white/inactive and when I move the mose over the element it doesn't react. How to make that work?

Comment: The CSS is invalid on the face of it. Are you writing in SCSS?

Comment: You mean something like that ? https://jsfiddle.net/boyu073j/7/ I don't really understand

Comment: Kévin Huang very close but you must put the circle and square together and when you move mouse cursor on any element the whole objects reacts. Look at the example of that guy: https://codepen.io/clayb/pen/KRPGWW The whole logo reacts but I can't repeat that method and I don't know why.